# Как импортировать данные в базу sqlite3 без указания некоторых полей с помощью sqlite клиента?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, csv

Например у меня есть таблица:

```
id(autoincrement),name(not null),status(not null),banned(default=false)
```

и данные для этой таблицы  в CSV:

```
   name;status
    john;online
    mike;offline
```

Какой **sqlite3 клиент**, не **sql запрос**, позволит мне импортировать данные только с этими полями?

Все кричат что у меня в таблице 4 поля, а в csv только два, да и если я сделаю id и banned пустыми будет вопить о несовместимости данных. В mysql например если в поле стоит autoincrement, то значение само выставляется.

Comment: добавь пустое поле в текстовом редакторе или электронной таблице, это ж пять секунд делается.

Comment: а sqlite3 не умеет сам читать csv файл, как это делает mysql? я же так понимаю, что insert (name,status) values (john;online) у вас работает?

Comment: наверняка , не пробовал. я думаю это на уровне клиента sqlite проблема.

Comment: ну и попробуйте что-то такое 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE thetable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY ""
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(name, status);`

Comment: нее так не пойдет, дело в том что это не мне надо, а людям далеким от всего этого.

Comment: мне нужен просто какой то клиент sqlite, какой сможет импортнуть такие данные. может кто-то  знает такой...

Comment: идея в том что любой sqlite клиент предоставляет функционал редактирования и добавления из коробки. но требует пряморукого рукоприкладства при данных манипуляциях. хоть бери свой пиши, склоняюсь к тому  что проще будет написать одну прогу какая будет заполнять только поля требующие данные((( уже ракеты назад возвращаются а до сих пор такие простые вещи не сделали(((